# Custom Post Type “Event”: chronological list of recurring events

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, events, custom-post-types

i'm looking for a good and easy way to have a custom post type "event" that can have multiple dates. (I have tested about 20 plugins). I think i have no problem building a metabox allowing the user to duplicate the field group "date and time" multiple times. But **how would a query look like that creates a chronological list of events from the meta data?**

(The project is a playing schedule for a theatre. Productions play on several dates.) Thank you!

Comment: this depends on the way you are storing the data, every date and time as a field or all of the as an array?

Comment: I haven't set up the metabox yet. If storing the data as an array is useful i will do it this way. I'm thinking of using WPAlchemy for duplicating fields: http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/

Comment: Think it may be better manageable to do it as a hierarchical post type. Event = first level, individual sessions = second level.

Comment: BTW: Since you tested 20 of them, can you recommend one? I need to replace the old Event Calendar Plugin with something a little more modern. But i need a calendar widget that shows the events.

Comment: @wyrfel: I want the administration of events to be as simple as possible. - A meta box with a date field - An option to duplicate the field - All dates saved as an array.

Comment: ... but my programming skills are quite limited, so i don't know how to query and list the events in chronological order.

Comment: @wyrfel: i cannot recommend a plugin. I checked if mulitple (inordinate) dates were supported and moved on if not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a plan:

1. Store the dates as individual custom fields with the same meta_key (ex: start_date)
2. JOIN the wp_posts table with the wp_postmeta table, *without* a GROUP BY (to allow the same event to appear more than once)
3. ORDER BY start_date

The full query would look like this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, meta_value AS start_date
FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (ID = post_ID)
WHERE post_type = 'event'
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND meta_key = 'start_date'
ORDER BY start_date
```

PS: This requires you store the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, which you should do anyway, for compatibility with mysql2date() etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @scripu! I have to work on another project today, but i'll try your solution as soon as possible!

Comment: I don't understand how to save multiple dates of the same event with the same meta_key. Could you please point that out? Thank you!

Comment: Just call `add_post_meta( $post_id, 'start_date', $date );` for each date. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Comment: Perfect! It works! For now only with the WP built-in custom fields. I have to figure out how to do it with my own fields. Thank you very much, @scribu!

Comment: Hey, I find you answer very helpful, thanks for that! I wonder if I can implement such a thing and query the events to results only the events from today on (e.g. start_date >= TODAY)? Thanks :)