# How to store multiple input values with same meta_key

Tags: metabox, post-meta

is there a way to store the input value from multiple custom meta box fields with the same `meta_key`?
I use the following code to store ONE value for the `meta_key` 'startdate':

```
function startdate() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $startdate = $custom["startdate"][0];
  ?>

<label>Startdate</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="startdate" value="<?php echo $startdate; ?>"/>

<?php }

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "startdate", $_POST["startdate"]);
}
```

If i had a second input field, how can i store its value with a different `meta_id` but the same `meta_key` (startdate)? Thank you very much!

*(If i use the built-in custom field functionality i can save multiple values for the same meta key...)*

Comment: Yes, just create an array of the data, update your field names to, `name="startdate[]"`

Comment: My Problem is, i have a solution for a custom query that works without arrays. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/custom-post-type-event-chronological-list-of-recurring-events/10390#10390 I don't know how to do the query with an array.

Comment: what are you trying to get out of the query?

Comment: I'm trying to get a chronological list of events. The crux is that each event (custom post) can have multiple dates, added as meta data. @Scribu pointed out how to do a query if the meta data is stored as individual custom fields with the same meta_key http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/custom-post-type-event-chronological-list-of-recurring-events

Comment: Any reason you can't use the native custom field functionality to enter these dates? Since you're storing it in meta anyway, why not enter these dates in the native metabox?

Comment: @t31os: If you ask me, the custom field UI is one of the crappiest bits of UI left in WP. It's for developers, not for users. Hence i can't blame anyone who wants to implement a metabox instead.

Comment: The dates are just a small part of the custom post type. The project is a theatre's website. This custom post type is for the productions. A production has images, dates, times, cast, director, location, description and so on... I need the interface to be very clean and intuitive. Right now i'm worried i got bogged down on this "multiple values / same key" thing, and better should have looked for a query that works with an array... Oh man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your form as suggested:

```
function startdate() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    echo "<label>Startdates</label><br/>";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($custom["startdate"]);$i++) {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"startdate[".$i."]\" value=\"".$custom["startdate"][$i]."\" />";
    }
}
```

You'll have to remove and reinstate your individual postmeta entries:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details($post_id) {
    if ($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) $post_id = $parent_id;

    if (!empty($_POST['startdate']) && is_array($_POST['startdate'])) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'startdate');
        foreach ($_POST['startdate'] as $startdate) {
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'startdate', $startdate);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, of course, you'll need to add some sort of add/remove mechanism to your metabox form, probably through JS.

Comment: Wow, almost there! Two issues i have: **(1)** When i create a new post (event) i get a warning in edit post area: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". When i enter dates into the form and save the post, the input values get stored correctly as individual postmeta entries (i see them in the db) and the warning disappears. But **(2)** on reload the meta_values are not set as input form values, so the form inputs appear to be empty. Any ideas how to solve those issues? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Christoph: Sorry, slackerstupidness on my side. For one, `wp_is_post_revision()` takes the post id as parameter, then, i didn't adjust the value attribute of the inputs properly in the form part, and finally, i now added some basic sanity checks to the update function. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [t31os](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1468/t31os) try changing your form inputs to use `name="startdate[]"` then loop through the array saving each value:

```
foreach ($_POST["startdate"] as $datevalue) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "startdate", $datevalue);
}
```

Comment: For anyone still reading this page, this answer is wrong. each iteration will overwrite the value of the post_meta instead of adding additional post_meta with the same name.